# PostgreSQL -- Clean way of extracting protobuf field via SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, protocol-buffers

I have been trying to figure out how to cleanly extract *some_value* from something that looks like this:

```
SELECT protobuff_text FROM table_name;
>>
resource_id {
   high_part: 10310138280989442894
   low_part: 12186277462739912197
}
...
}
known_field_name: some_value
mask {
  points {
...
```

It should be extracted without assuming anything about what happens before or after it besides the newline.  This is easy in MySQL... but I have been having a hard time figuring it out in postgres.

Any PostgreSQL experts out there who can help me with this?

P.S. The string that is inserted into the database is created via `com.google.protobuf.TextFormat.printToString(Message m)`.

Comment: Why don't you show the "easy" way of MySQL?

Comment: Have you tried `regexp_matches` function?

Comment: Personally, I'd use PL/Pythonu or PL/Perl to load a protocol buffers library, parse it properly, and return the desired data.

Comment: I agree that's a more 'proper' way of doing it, but this is just a command-line support tool that we use internally for support and debugging.  Also with your approach it would require querying the database twice via PyGreSQL (the extracted value is part of the JOIN), and would be more hassle to write than the two-line bash script the query is currently in :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(protobuff_text,'resource_id\s*\{\s*high\_part\:\s*([0-9]*)\s*low\_part\:\s*([0-9]*)\s*\}') 
FROM table_name;
```

This regex will get you the numeric values, you shown in the example.

For the `known_field_name` try something like:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(protobuff_text,'known_field_name\:\s*(\w*)') 
FROM table_name;
```

Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

Comment: To get the first element (remove curly braces) -- SELECT (regexp_matches(protobuff_text,'known_field_name\:\s*(\w*)'))[1]